# Matlab how to sample polygon circumference at constant distances

Tags: matlab

I need a "matlab way" to get n samples of a polygon circumference, at constant distances on the circumference.
The polygon is given by 2 vectors, X and Y, representing the corners.

Could not find a built in function for this, or a one line solution

Note, the polygon could be a polyline for all i care.

For example, sample(x,y,100) would give 100 samples of the polyline or polygon defined by x,y at equal distances, just like 1:10:1000 would do for a straight line.

I hope i made the question clear, please ask if not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to interpolate non monotonic data.

You can do something like :

```
n = 1000; % # of sample points.

x1 = (rand(1,4)-0.5)*100; %random x value
y1 = (rand(1,4)-0.5)*100; %random y value

x1 = [x1,x1(1)]; %Close the polygon
y1 = [y1,y1(1)]; %Close the polygon

t = [0,cumsum(sqrt(diff(x1).^2+diff(y1).^2))]; %cumsum(euclidian distance) => t(end) = perimeter.
ti = linspace(0,t(end),n);
x = interp1(t,x1,ti);
y = interp1(t,y1,ti);

plot(x1,y1,'ro',x,y,'b-')
```

There is just the small tricks with "t" in order to interpolate non monotonic data.

Optional:
If you replace `interp1` by `spline` or `pchip` you can smooth your curve.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful way of doing it. Works like a charm